# Gitlab code quality takes long time to run

Tags: java, spring, git, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a clean spring boot project and I'm testing ci on it.
I've created a job to check code quality but it takes a long time to run(over 20 minutes). I didn't find why it happens.

```
image: maven:3.3-jdk-8


cache:
  paths:
  - .m2/
  untracked: true

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2"

stages:
- check
- test
- build

code_quality:
  image: docker:stable
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  allow_failure: true
  services:
  - docker:stable-dind
  script:
  - export SP_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_SERVER_VERSION" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1-\2-stable/')
  - docker run
      --env SOURCE_CODE="$PWD"
      --volume "$PWD":/code
      --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/codequality:latest" /code
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json



run-tests-myapp:
  stage: test
  script:
  - mvn --batch-mode test
  only:
  - master
  - dev
  - merge_requests
```

Comment: have the same issue, did you find a reason?